# How to detect lane without line in lane in opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm stuck in the detect lane with opencv, the problem here is it detect all the edges of the image, but i want to just detect the lane, how can i do this, i try to find solution but it not works. [image]

[image]

Comment: We need at least the origin image before the process to test, or we can only give some advice(like just draw the line which degree is between 45~135 or only longer than the length you decide).

Comment: Canny is usually a beginner's doom. throw all the code away. -- as Ema already pointed out, we need to see untouched source data. -- you might need to use AI. you need a "segmentation" of the picture into road, not-road, maybe even sky, buildings, trees, pedestrians, ... -- if not AI, then even texture analysis might get you further than just thresholds. your scene has no lighting, so simple thresholding will probably be good enough already.

Comment: Please avoid posting images (or worse, links to images) of code or errors. Anything text-based (code and errors) should be posted as text directly in the question itself and formatted properly as a [mre]. You can get more [formatting help here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). You can also read about [why you shouldn't post images/links of code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Gaussian Blur** to avoid it.

Basically, the concept is to blur the picture a bit and filter out unnecessary lines.

All I usually do is,

```
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(grey, (3,3), 5) #Variable for your case
```

References:

- https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gaabe8c836e97159a9193fb0b11ac52cf1
- https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html

Besides that, after blurring, you can also use `ROI` to fix the point of view of your car and filter out other details if needed.

```
vertices = np.array([[10,500], [10,300], [300,200], [500,200], [800,300], [800,500]]) #creates roi part. it will be totally dependent on your region of interest
processed_img = roi(processed_img, [vertices])
```

After processing it, then try to draw lines. It will help you greatly.

References:

- https://youtu.be/h98js2usaVo

Comment: a blur will make *every* line harder to detect. that means it'll affect the "noise" *and the desired lines* both. -- in the current state of the question, it's hard to give any advice.

Comment: True that. But it seemed like he may get a good idea of what options he may have he can do after seeing my approaches in my mind.